# Copy data of vector<MyStruct> to a pointer of a vector<MyStruct>

Tags: c++, c++17

I have 2 vectors: one is of MyStruct

```
std::vector<MyStruct> v1 = get_some_data();
```

And the other one is a pointer to a memory

```
void * p = get_memory_by_NIF_of_Erlang(..., v1.size());
std::vector<MyStruct> *v2 = static_cast<std::vector<MyStruct>*>(p);
```

I want **to copy data** of `v1` to `v2`. I don't want to point `v2` to `v1` because it's already been created and points to somewhere else.

How can I do it properly?

This won't compile and besides it may be wrong all together:

```
  for (auto i = 0; i < v1.size(); i++) {
    *(v2 + i * sizeof(MyStruct)) = v1[i]; //error: no viable overloaded '='
  }
```

What's an idiomatic way?

Comment: You almost never need pointers to standard containers. What is the underlying problem you try to solve by a function like `get_memory_for_vector()`? Why do you need to use pointers to the vector? And a vector isn't like an array, you can't use pointer arithmetic the way you do, as you treat `v2` as a pointer to the first element of an array of vectors, not as a pointer to a single vector (and the pointer arithmetic is wrong anyway)..

Comment: `std::vector<T>` is not a plain array of `T`, it allocates memory internally, and stores objects on heap. Its own size is about 24 bytes (3 pointers). It is not clear what `get_memory_for_vector` is supposed to do. What `memory`?

Comment: The idiomatic way is `std::vector<MyStruct> *v2 = new std::vector<MyStruct>(v1);` but like everyone else I'm wondering why you feel you need to do this.

Comment: It seems what you really trying to do is have the memory allocated by v2 come from somewhere different than the regular heap. In that case you should write a *custom allocator* for use with your vector. Tutorial here https://blog.feabhas.com/2019/03/thanks-for-the-memory-allocator/

Comment: @john can't I intead iterate and assign values one by one?

Comment: maybe you can have a look at [std::span](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span), but that's c++20

Answer (score 1):

Is it achievable by doing something like this?

```
std::vector<_element>* vec2 = new std::vector<_element>();
vec2->reserve(vec1.size()); //So we have enough space

for(size_t i = 0; i < vec1.size(); i++)
{
    vec2->push_back(vec1[i]);
}
```

It should copy everything from the first vector to the second, and they are completely separated so deleting the first one won't affect the second.

Comment: you see my code? how can I do what I want to with my case?

Comment: Okay I'm gonna edit the answer because now I see it

Comment: Is this new answer what you're going for?

Comment: @pavel I'm happy then, but just out of curiosity, what are you using that pointer for? Because you can pass the vectors by value or by reference and it can achieve pretty much anything for you, and it is probably more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

1. If `void* p` points to a memory buffer that you want to use to store `v1`'s elements.

One thing you can do to use the given memory buffer to store `std::vector` elements is to employ [polymorphic allocators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/memory_resource) and [`std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/monotonic_buffer_resource):

```
using T = int;
std::vector<T> v1{1, 2, 3};

const auto buffer_size = v1.size() * sizeof(T);
void* p = /* get_some_memory(...) */ std::malloc(buffer_size);

std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource pool(
    p, buffer_size, std::pmr::null_memory_resource());

std::pmr::vector<T> v2(v1.begin(), v1.end(), &pool);
for (auto x : v2)
    std::cout << x << ' ';             // Output: 1 2 3

// dirty hack
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < v2.size(); ++i)
    std::cout << *((T*)p + i) << ' ';  // Output: 1 2 3
```

The vector `v2` will use `memory` buffer to store elements copied from the vector `v1`.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/mf-NV8)

---

2. If `void* p` points to a `std::vector` object and you want to copy elements into it.

```
auto v2 = static_cast<std::vector<T>*>(p);
v2->assign(v1.begin(), v1.end());
// or just
*v2 = v1;
```

If there is no `std::vector` at `p`, the behaviour is undefined. Note that `std::vector<T>` is not a plain array of `T`, it allocates memory internally and stores objects on heap (their location is not related to `p` at all). Its own size is typically 24 bytes (3 pointers, 8 bytes each).